# error when installing PHPMYADMIN

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I was trying to install PHPMYADMIN and got the error

E: Sub-process /urs/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried reinstalling it but it just give me this error
not sure how to fix it

any help would be appricated

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server php7.0-mysql
[sudo] password for abandola1: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.0-mysql is already the newest version (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1).
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.20-0ubuntu0.17.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.22-0ubuntu0.17.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libapache2-mod-php:
 libapache2-mod-php depends on libapache2-mod-php7.0; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0:
 php7.0 depends on libapache2-mod-php7.0 | php7.0-fpm | php7.0-cgi; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.0 is not configured yet.
  Package php7.0-fpm is not installed.
  Package php7.0-cgi is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
 libapache2-mod-php
 php7.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's easy to install phpMyAdmin from Ubuntu's repository, it is not the latest version. You can install it manually from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/.

**Install phpMyAdmin:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unzip
cd /var/www/html
wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.8.0/phpMyAdmin-4.8.0-all-languages.zip
unzip phpMyAdmin-4.8.0-all-languages.zip
rm phpMyAdmin-4.8.0-all-languages.zip
```

**Some explanations:**

`sudo apt-get update` - update the repositories list
`sudo apt-get install unzip` - install unzip (if not already installed) that is required to unzip the phpMyAdmin archive
`cd /var/www/html` - go into the directory where you want to install it (must be publicly available)
`wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/...languages.zip` - download the phpMyAdmin archive
`unzip phpMyAdmin-4.8.0-all-languages.zip` - unpack the archive
`rm phpMyAdmin-4.8.0-all-languages.zip` - remove the archive, as it's no longer needed

**How to access phpMyAdmin:**

Now you can access the phpMyAdmin as `http://www.your_domain.tld/phpMyAdmin-4.8.0-all-languages/` or by ip address `http://ip_address/phpMyAdmin-4.8.0-all-languages/`